# UI thread didn't refresh with thread update although using invoke

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

On a form I want to update a `TextBox`. The update is done from a thread.
The thread is started like that:

```
ComThread = New Thread(AddressOf ComPlcVar.Scan_PLC)
ComThread.IsBackground = True
ComThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
ComThread.Start()
Console.WriteLine("Do start thread")
```

The update function is something like that:

```
If frmAcc.L_Cas_G.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim d As New L_Cas_Trait_CallBack(AddressOf L_Cas_Trait)
    frmAcc.L_Cas_G.Invoke(d, New Object() {Str})
Else
    frmAcc.L_Cas_G.Text = Str & ControlChars.CrLf & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyy") & " " & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
End if
```

The delegate of the function is declared.

```
 Public Delegate Sub L_Cas_Trait_CallBack(ByVal str As String)
 Public Sub L_Cas_Trait(Str As String)
```

But when I am calling the update function from the thread my UI isn't updated.

It's seems it's only an UI problem because when I put writeline on the texchanged methode of the form I got an event with the right string display on the console...

```
Private Sub L_Cas_G_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles L_Cas_G.TextChanged
    Console.WriteLine(L_Cas_G.Text)
End Sub
```

Do anybody got an idea on what I am missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint, does the code actually go in the function?

Comment: If Not frmAcc.L_Cas_G.InvokeRequired Then Throw New Exception("Don't use the default instance in a thread!!!")

Comment: the_lotus -> yes it goes in the function  Hans Passant -> i don't understant what you mean by don't use the default instance?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you use Cross threading some where on your page. Try use AppendText Instead.

Something like this maybe:

```
Private Delegate Sub AppendTextBoxDelegate(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)

Private Sub AppendTextBox(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal txt As String)
    If TB.InvokeRequired Then
        TB.Invoke(New AppendTextBoxDelegate(AddressOf AppendTextBox), New Object() {TB, txt})
    Else
        TB.AppendText(txt)
    End If
End Sub
```

And use it as followed:

```
AppendTextBox(YOURTEXTBOX, ADD YOUR CONTENT HERE)
```

Answer came from  here: [Update Text Box Properly when Cross-threading in Visual Basic (VS 2012 V11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529092/update-text-box-properly-when-cross-threading-in-visual-basic-vs-2012-v11)

Please Check the full examples on the page. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it doesn't work better. Still my text box doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

In my test i found that the *invokerequiered* method never return true.
I read that it can happen when the handle of the control isn't created but i test with *IsHandleCreated* and it's seems ok.

As i didn't find a solution to this i decided to try another method to update tu UI.

So i found the *syncContext.Post* method and it's works as i expected.
I declare :

Public syncContext As SynchronizationContext

before starting my thread i do :

```
syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext()
```

To update my text (or label) i do :

```
syncContext.Post(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf UpdateStatus), Str_Tmp)
```

this call :

```
  Private Sub UpdateStatus(ByVal State As Object)
        frmAcc.L_Cas_G.Text = CType(State, String)
  End Sub
```

Now it works.

Thanks all for the help.