# Show and Hide a label in a panel in VB

Tags: vb.net

I was surprised to find that in VB one can not easily set the font and backcolour of a tooltip item by it's default properties so I thought I would create my own.

```
Private aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub Panel1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseHover
    Hover("How's about that")
End Sub

Private Sub Hover(ByRef Tip As String)
    If Not lblToolTip.Visible Then
        lblToolTip.Text = Tip
        lblToolTip.Location = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
        lblToolTip.Visible = True
        lblToolTip.BringToFront()
        StartTimer()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StartTimer()
    aTimer.Interval = 2000
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf aTimer_Elapsed)
    aTimer.Start()
End Sub

Sub aTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    aTimer.Stop()
    lblToolTip.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Everything goes ok until I try to hide the label when I get the error -
'Cross - thread operation Not valid: Control 'lblToolTip' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

I have researched the error for a couple of days but I am afraid it is a bit too deep a thread for an 80 old year after a stroke. I would appreciate any pointers to direct me to the solution.

Comment: Best to use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.  Or fix with `aTimer.SynchronizingObject = Me`

Answer (score 1):

You could have used a [Forms Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0) and not had this problem.

Since you didn't, replace your aTimer_Elapsed method with this.

```
Sub aTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    aTimer.Stop()
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                       lblToolTip.Visible = False
                   End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't use the forms.timer as I wish to use a module for all forms

Answer (score 1):

Try use Delegate

```
    Private aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
    Private Delegate Sub SafeCallDelegate(ByVal label As Label, ByVal Visible As Boolean, ByVal Text As String)

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseHover
        Hover("How's about that")
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartTimer()
        aTimer.Interval = 2000
        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf aTimer_Elapsed)
        aTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub aTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        aTimer.Stop()
        SetLabelProperty(lblToolTip, False)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetLabelProperty(ByVal label As Label, ByVal Visible As Boolean, Optional ByVal Text As String = "")
        If label.InvokeRequired Then
            label.Invoke(New SafeCallDelegate(AddressOf SetLabelProperty), New Object() {label, Visible, Text})
        Else
            label.Visible = Visible
            label.Location = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
            label.Text = Text
            lblToolTip.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Hover(ByRef Tip As String)
        If Not lblToolTip.Visible Then
            SetLabelProperty(lblToolTip, True, Tip)
            StartTimer()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Look this example:
[Update Text Box Properly when Cross-threading in Visual Basic (VS 2012 V11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529092/update-text-box-properly-when-cross-threading-in-visual-basic-vs-2012-v11/16529250)

Comment: Thanks for the assist which I got to work but I wasn't happy with the complexity.  Continued to work on drawing the tooltrip and eventually got it in 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

This was the result

```
Public Sub ToolTip_Draw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs)
    e.DrawBackground()
    e.DrawBorder()
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, New Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, New PointF(2, 2))
End Sub

Public Sub ToolTip_Popup(sender As Object, e As PopupEventArgs)
    Dim Sz As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sender.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl), New Font("Arial", 10))
    e.ToolTipSize = New Size(Sz.Width, Sz.Height + 4)
End Sub
```

The backcolour is set in the properties.  The size is determined by the PipUp.